# Doesn't install mysql module for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problems installing module mysql for node.js. I use npm install mysql and this what I have in cmd
[image]

Comment: Might be a problem with the npmjs repository or your connection to that server. Just try it again.

Comment: Did you install the database? msql node module is not the database itself.

Comment: Any errors in the console while installing via NPM?

Comment: What is the error you are getting...

Comment: I try. I can't install any module

Comment: If you can't install any module using npm then you should clarify this in your question and its title. Is it the first time you try to install something? Or where you able to install something using npm before?

Comment: it's the first time i'm try to install something

Comment: you should check your proxy settings and also check if you are able to install other npm modules

Comment: what `npm` version do you have (`npm -v`) an which windows version?

Comment: Windows 7, npm 3.3.12